# How to save changes on UWP?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I have a simple and basic question: how do I make my app save changes on the textbox and other editable tools (like radiobuttons/colors etc)?

I am coding a UWP app on Visual Studio. 
When I lunch the app on VS, the text I write in the textboxes disapear when I close the app.

Sorry I just started a few days ago and can't find a solution...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you need to store that data locally, when you closing your app. so when you restart app first fetch data from that local storage and save or append it in your textbox.

**You can use below two ways to store it.**

1. Create one text file and store your data in it, so you can fetch data whenever your app 
   is restarted.
2. you can use settings for store local data. please check below link for more information.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/settings-learning-track

Comment: I indeed found some topics about this. But where do I have to put those ApplicationDataContainers codes? Is it in the App.xaml.cs page? If so, where?

Comment: If you are storing data in text file, you do not need to worry about where to store it. Just give path of your app's folder.

Answer (score 0):

By localSettings, You can store your data locally in your machine.

```
public static class LocalSettingsHelper
{
    private static ApplicationDataContainer _localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

    /// <summary>
    /// Create Local Settings storage Container
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="container">Container</param>
    /// <param name="containerValue">ContainerValue</param>
    /// <param name="value">Value</param>
    internal static void SetContainer<T>(string container, string containerValue, T value)
    {
        var containerName = _localSettings.CreateContainer(container, ApplicationDataCreateDisposition.Always);
        _localSettings.Containers[container].Values[containerValue] = value != null ? JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value) : null;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get Local Settings Container 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="container">Container</param>
    /// <param name="containerValue">ContainerValue</param>
    /// <returns>Value as Type</returns>
    internal static T GetContainerValue<T>(string container, string containerValue)
    {
        var containerName = _localSettings.CreateContainer(container, ApplicationDataCreateDisposition.Always);
        string currentValue = _localSettings.Containers[container].Values[containerValue] as string;
        if (currentValue == null)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(currentValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! I will try that. Do I have to put those codes in the pages concerned? Or do I have to write those on the App.cs page?

Comment: Add this as a New class, or you can put those static methods in your App.cs

Comment: Alright I tried this but the Json fonction doesn't work... Do I forget something?

Comment: You need to add Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package in your project

Comment: Alright, I did add this and the project works. Still doesn't save anything though. Is it because I still generate it using VS? Do I have to try after lunching the .exe once the app is done?

Comment: yes you have to do this once, when your project will complete and deploy.

Comment: Okay, I will try this once I deploy the app then. So with those codes, the radio buttons and colors that changed when the app was active will stay the sale when I re open the app right? What baout text boxes? Do I have to put a code with a button to save them? Or will the text I enter on the textboxes will stay? At the moment I only have textboxes with no text in them... What do you think? Thank you :)